# linkerd Dtab expression not transforming as expected

Tags: linkerd

I've got [linkerd](http://linkerd.io) running locally per [this getting started page](https://linkerd.io/getting-started/locally/), and the basic proxy example works.  My use case requires me to proxy web requests to one of several .NET WebApi services, so I made a little sample WebApi project running locally that has two routes:

1. localhost:58371 returns `hello world`
2. localhost:58371/api/values returns `["value1", "value2"]`

### Mapping requests with matching routes

If I leave my `linkerd.yaml` file like it comes out-of-the-box:

`routers:
- protocol: http
  dtab: |
    /svc => /#/io.l5d.fs`

then mapping routes directly works:

`curl -H "Host: web" http://localhost:4140/` --> `hello world`

`curl -H "Host: web" http://localhost:4140/api/values` --> `["value1", "value2"]`

### Mapping mismatched routes

Now, I would like to map `localhost:4140/tacos` --> `localhost:58371/api/values`. So, I update my .yaml file to:

`routers:
- protocol: http
  dtab: |
    /svc => /#/io.l5d.fs;
    /tacos => /api/values;`

and restart linkerd.

**However, `http://localhost:4140/` always seems to resolve to `http://localhost:58371/tacos`, not `http://localhost:58371/api/values`.  What am I not understanding?**

I've read through a bunch of example dtab transformations on linkerd's site, and I've played around with a bunch of different configurations in my yaml file. Surely it's just something silly that I'm missing because this seems like a really simple use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, linkerd uses the value of the HTTP Host header associated with the request to route traffic. In your example, you're setting `Host: web`, so all traffic is going to the "web" service that's found in service discovery, regardless of the request URI's path.

So rather than sending your request to `localhost:4140/tacos`, you should send it to `-H 'Host: tacos' localhost:4140/api/values`. You would also need to adjust your dtab as follows:

```
/svc       => /#/io.l5d.fs;
/svc/tacos => /svc/web;
```

That will route all traffic with `Host: tacos` to the "web" service that's found in service discovery. This is just the default configuration, however.

If you're interested in routing based on the URI path instead of the HTTP Host header, you can use linkerd's [path identifier](https://linkerd.io/config/1.1.0/linkerd/index.html#path-identifier). Something like:

```
routers:
- protocol: http
  identifier:
    kind: io.l5d.path
    segments: 1
  dtab: |
    /svc => /#/io.l5d.fs;
```

With that configuration, a request to `localhost:4140/api/values` would be routed to the "api" service in service discovery, and a request to `localhost:4140/tacos` would be routed to the "tacos" service, and both of those routing decisions can be changed by modifying your dtab.

I should note that linkerd does not do arbitrary HTTP URI path rewriting based on dtab rules. Since it's a proxy, it expects to proxy the request without modification, with a few exceptions (such as the `consume` option on the path identifier). You could always write a [linkerd plugin](https://linkerd.io/in-depth/plugin/) though that would fit your specific use case.

Comment: I want to do this:
`curl -H "Host: web" http://localhost:4140/tacos`, but have it route to `http://127.0.0.1:53781/api/values`, where `127.0.0.1 53781` live in the `web` file inside `disco/`. This isn't possible?

A more "real-world" use case might be that my clients just want to call an endpoint in linkerd called `/createSession`, but have it route to, say, the SessionManagementService endpoint called `/api/Session/Create`.  

I played around with the path identifier and was able to do basically the same `/apples` to `/apples` routing without needing to pass in the `Host` header.

Comment: wrote:
>  I should note that linkerd does not do arbitrary HTTP URI path rewriting based on dtab rules. Since it's a proxy, it expects to proxy the request without modification...


Isn't that what [this page](https://linkerd.io/in-depth/dtabs/) is all about?  If I can do `/smitten` to `/smitten       => /USA/CA/SF/Octavia/432;`, why can't I do `/tacos` to `/api/values`?

Comment: The paths that are used in dtabs aren't equivalent to HTTP request paths. Dtabs are protocol independent, and are only useful for mapping a logical name (`/smitten`) to a concrete destination (`/USA/CA/SF/Octavia/432`). The dtab rewrites have no bearing on the request itself, only the request's destination. You can find more info about this in the [in-depth routing guide](https://linkerd.io/in-depth/routing/).

Comment: I see now.  I had my blinders on thinking that dtabs did more than they did.  Was thinking they did route transformation as well, but I see now that it's just mapping `service name` to `client name`.  Thanks for helping me see the light.